# Javascript validation in mulitstep form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, multi-step

I have a multistep form needs additional validation for password, email, credit card expiry date.
As there is a function validateForm I want to add to this so that it also checks the password has 8 char and email is valid ('@').

The main issue is the for loop that says input is valid/invalid before allowing user to go to next step in form. At the moment it just checks if there is anything in each box, if so it goes next page. I need it to also check that the password/email is valid as per above requests.

```
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) { /*need to add in password/email validation to below but unsure how */
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Complete Order";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        document.getElementById("orderForm").submit();
        return false;
    }
    showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (y[i].value == "") {
            y[i].className += "invalid";
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is there an error or you just need the code for the email validation?

Comment: I want to specify formatting required for password e.g. 8 char, upper/lower case req, num req and for expiry date on credit card to prompt when user inputs expired date etc. Email address must use '@' etc. No idea how to add to this code without breaking functions for the steps.

Comment: For the password and email validation you can use Regex.
For the Credit card expiration validation, you can check the date.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can edit the HTML elements and add id's to the input fields, you can simply use `document.getElementById` to get each specific input.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <input type="password" id="myPassword" />
   <input type="email" id="myEmail" />
 </body>
</html>

function validateForm() {
  const pwInput = document.getElementById('myPassword');
  if( pwInput && pwInput.value.length < 5) { 
       
     console.log('password not valid');
  }

  const emailInput = document.getElementById('myEmail');
  if(emailInput && emailInput.search(/@/) === -1) {
   console.log('email not valid');
  }
}
```

This sounds like homework, so this is some additional food for thought for production code.

- While doing password validation on the client side is okay, server side must absolutely do password validation.
- Email validation is very tricky to do. You can use a regex you find, but even the ones on Stack Overflow are filled with caveats and test cases that don't work. For production code, using a library along with email verification is your best bet.